# How to insert text rendered with CSS in CKEditor?

Tags: css, ckeditor

I am programming some plugins that insert elements like pictures and tables inside the editor. What I need is to see these elements in the editor rendered with their final aspect. I mean, I need to add css classes to the editor and use them to render text in the editor, and I want to do it on the fly, seing those elements rendered in the editor.

Is there any way to do it? Can I see the elementes correctly rendered inside the editor inserting them with a plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You will have a dropdown list in your editor, where you can select configured CSS styles to be applied in your content.

How to do it you can find in the documentation:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles